# SNMP (Ubuntu 18.04) on AudioCodes M500L not working

Tags: snmp, nagios, snmpd

i try to monitor values with nagios over snmp from my two audiocodes SBCs (M500L).

For these i download two MIBs "AC-ALARM-MIB" + "IP-MIB_rfc4293" from https://github.com/librenms/librenms/tree/master/mibs/audiocodes rename it to .txt at the end and upload it to my ubuntu server in path /usr/share/snmp/mibs/.

Then i try to use the following command in command line.

```
snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u xxxxxx -a SHA -A xxxxx -x AES -X xxxxx 123.456.789.100 AcAlarm:acActiveAlarmName
```

and i get the following output

```
AcAlarm::acActiveAlarmName = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

I try to find out the OID from these in MIB Browser - seems like it is " .1.3.6.1.4.1.5003.11.1.1.1.1.5". When i use these OID i get same output.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: `snmpget` requires you to present all necessary MIB documents, so you need to dig further into what documents are missing, http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS

Comment: Seems like something is not ok. AC-ALARM-MIB.my is uploaded to /usr/share/snmp/mibs with 0644 rights. `root@Monitoring:~# snmptranslate -m +AC-ALARM-MIB -IR -On acActiveAlarmName
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (AC-ALARM-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Unknown object identifier: acActiveAlarmName`

Answer (score 0):

SNMP treats all values as being entries in some database. OIDs are used to identify entries in this conceptual database. MIB files allow an SNMP manager to translate OIDs into a human-readable string, with an accompanying textual description.

The issue here is not that the MIB files are bad, or the OIDs are wrong, the problem is that, either the devices that hold this (imaginary) database do not support the entries you are trying to access, or that your user is not authorized to access those entries. A simple way to find out what OIDs are supported would be to do a full walk of the database, using something like `snmpwalk <hostname> 1.3.6.1`